# XML Encoding generated from PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, servlets, character-encoding

I am doing an assignment for class where I have to use a Java Servlet running on Tomcat and have it message a php file to scrape IMDB for movie information and return it as XML to the servlet. It seems to not want to accept any encoding I give it as I continuously get XML tags such as the ones below.

```
      <result cover="url" title="Pok&#xE9;mon" year="1998 TV Series" director="N/A" rating="7.8" details="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0176385/"/>
```

Where title of Pokemon should have an accent over the e («é»). I have the following php code to generate the xml. (Important parts only)

```
    <?php header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $rsp = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement("rsp"));
    $xml->encoding = 'utf-8';

    $titleNames[$i] = utf8_encode($title_tmp[1]);

    $results = $rsp->appendChild($xml->createElement("results"));
    $results->setAttribute("total", $tableRows);

    $item->setAttribute("title", $titleNames[$i]);

    echo $xml->saveXML();
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in figuring out how to correctly display special characters!

Comment: Is the communication java<->php via xml a requirement of the assignment?

Comment: Yea the full communication is HTML AJAX -> Servlet -> Php (XML) -> Servlet (XML to JSON) -> HTML (JSON). I can't tell where the encoding is not working.

Comment: `&#xE9;` is a "correct" representation of the character é - it's the numeric character reference of e-acute, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference . But I don't know why one of the parsers/writers chose this representation...

Comment: I can see `utf8_encode()`. Are you actually saving your PHP source code as ISO-8859-1?

Comment: From doing more research and getting more pieces to this, it looks like the problem is as follows. I get "Law &#x26; Order" from IMDB, but when I used setAttribute("title", "Law &#x26; Order") it seems to encode it to "Law &amp;#x26; Order"

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say what's wrong from your code fragments (which don't even run) but `$xml->encoding = 'utf-8'` should work. Please compare:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$rsp = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement("rsp"));
$rsp->setAttribute("title", 'Pokémon');
echo $xml->saveXML();
/*
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rsp title="Pok&#xE9;mon"/>
*/
```

... with:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->encoding = 'utf-8';
$rsp = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement("rsp"));
$rsp->setAttribute("title", 'Pokémon');
echo $xml->saveXML();
/*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsp title="Pokémon"/>
*/
```

(These snippets are expected to be saved as UTF-8).

Comment: From doing more research and getting more pieces to this, it looks like the problem is as follows. I get "Law &#x26; Order" from IMDB, but when I used setAttribute("title", "Law &#x26; Order") it seems to encode it to "Law &amp;#x26; Order"

Comment: Of course, the `&` symbol needs to be encoded as `&amp;` because it has a special meaning in XML. You've obviously failing to decode what you read from IMDB.